# How to remove array if all keys acquired by another array in multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

can you please help me out in this. 
What will be the function to remove 4th and 5th array in PHP.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [10] => 98
            [11] => 1
            [433438] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [10] => 98
            [11] => 1
            [433438] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [13] => 98
            [11] => 2
            [433438] => 8
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [14] => 98
            [11] => 2
            [433438] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [10] => 18
            [11] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [14] => 18
            [11] => 2
        )

)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what is your condition for remove element?

Comment: array 4th and 5th having keys (10,11) & (14,11), which is already acquired by array 1st and 3rd. so have to remove all elements which are already acquired by any another parent element. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$base = [
    [10 => 98, 11 => 1, 433438 => 8],
    [10 => 98, 11 => 1, 433438 => 1],
    [13 => 98, 11 => 2, 433438 => 8],
    [14 => 98, 11 => 2, 433438 => 1],
    [10 => 18, 11 => 1],
    [14 => 18, 11 => 2],
];

$invalid = [];

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($base) - 1; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j <= count($base) - 1; $j++) {
        $refCount = count($base[$j]);
        $interSectCount = count(array_intersect(array_keys($base[$i]), array_keys($base[$j])));
        if (count($base[$i]) !== $refCount && $interSectCount === $refCount) {
            $invalid[] = $j;
        }
    }
}

foreach ($invalid as $item) {
    unset($base[$item]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_pop()` function which eliminates the last element of the array but if you use it two times you will get the desired result as

```
<?php
$data  = [
    1 => [1,2],
    2 => [1,3],
    3 => [1,4]
];
$value = array_pop($data);
$value = array_pop($data);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: we do not have static nodes to remove. As shown in question array 4th and 5th having keys (10,11) & (14,11), which is already acquired by array 1st and 3rd respectively. so have to dynamically  remove all elements which are already acquired by any another parent element.. Thanks